# jQuery count divs in specific div, then when a new div is added reset count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using .each to count divs inside another div, but I have multiple divs with the same class, and I want to count from 0 for each new div wrapper.

Sorry it's kind of hard to explain so here's a link to the workin jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1nds1put/

1.) Click "Add Seasonal Price Filter"

2.) Click "Add Price Rule", you'll see it says "Price Rule #1" (working fine)

3.) Click "Add Price Rule" again, you'll see it says "Price Rule #2" (still working fine)

4.) Click "Add Seasonal Price Filter" again

5.) Click "Add Price Rule" in the new seasonal price filter and you'll see it says "Price Rule #3" (not working, I want it to say "Price Rule #1" since it's in a different div)

Here's the function which calculates the number/counter:

```
function recacluclate() {

        $( ".price-rule-wrapper-outer").children('div').each(function(index) {
            $(this).find('.price-rule-number span').text(index + 1);
        });

        $( ".seasonal-filter-wrapper-outer").children('div').each(function(index) {
            $(this).find('.seasonal-filter-number span').text(index + 1);
        });

        $( ".seasonal-filter-wrapper-outer .price-rule-wrapper-outer").children('div').each(function(index) {
            $(this).find('.price-rule-number span').text(index + 1);
        });

        $( ".price-rule-wrapper-outer").children('div').each(function(index) {
            $(this).find('.standard-adult-weekday').attr('name', 'standard-adult-weekday-' + (index + 1));
            $(this).find('.standard-adult-weekend').attr('name', 'standard-adult-weekend-' + (index + 1));
            $(this).find('.standard-child-weekday').attr('name', 'standard-child-weekday-' + (index + 1));
            $(this).find('.standard-child-weekend').attr('name', 'standard-child-weekend-' + (index + 1));
        });

    }
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I think this is your problem here: `$( ".price-rule-wrapper-outer").children('div').each` - the `div` children of _all_ `.price-rule-wrapper-outer` elements are _combined_ into one collection here first, that you then loop over as a whole, getting one continuously counted index. What you actually want, is probably rather sth. like `$( ".price-rule-wrapper-outer").each(…)` - and then inside that you get the div children of that particular outer wrapper, and set the index for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
$( ".seasonal-filter-wrapper-outer .price-rule-wrapper-outer").children('div').each(function(index) {
    $(this).find('.price-rule-number span').text(index + 1);
});
```

with

```
$(".seasonal-filter-wrapper-outer .price-rule-wrapper-outer").each(function() {
  $(this).children('div').each(function(index) {
    $(this).find('.price-rule-number span').text(index + 1);
  });
})
```